# Wrong font in Vimix Grub theme

Tags: grub2, themes, fonts

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 and I've installed the Vimix Grub theme:

https://github.com/vinceliuice/grub2-themes

The theme is loading correctly, but the font I see on my screen is not the one displayed in the website screenshots (DejaVu Sans):

[image]

I believe Grub is not loading the font included in the theme, but I can't figure out how to fix this.

I've tried to install the theme using the following options, but the result was the same:

```
sudo ./install.sh -v
```

(Theme installed in /usr/share/grub/themes/Vimix/theme.txt)

```
sudo ./install.sh -v -b
```

(Theme installed in /boot/grub/themes/Vimix/theme.txt)

I've also tried to use the following option in `/etc/default/grub`, but that still didn't help.

```
GRUB_GFXMODE=1920x1080x32
```

Any idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that in the themes.txt file you must specify "DejaVu Sans Regular 16" in both the item_font and font fields, in order DejaVu Sans fonts to be applied to the theme.

Answer (score 0):

I found similar reports on the **grub2-themes** bug tracker:

- https://github.com/vinceliuice/grub2-themes/issues/43
- https://github.com/vinceliuice/grub2-themes/issues/15

According to the repository owner, pixelated fonts are normal in Grub because it doesn't support advanced functions of the graphics card (blurring or anti-alisasing). So maybe the font did apply correctly in my case.

The screenshots on the website look better because they were created in Inkscape.